# Clipboard.SetText() shows errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I have been using a simple web form application for url shortening in asp.net. I have sucessfully made my function and when i change the url it should automatically copies to clipboard.

I have made the text value to store in variable like

```
   shortUrl.Text = shortURL;
```

After this i am calling the Clipboard function

```
 clip_board(shortURL);
```

My function is

```
 public void clip_board(string shortUrl)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(shortUrl);
       Clipboard.SetText(shortUrl);

    }
```

Here the message box shows the shorten url but the `Clipboard.SetText()` showing error as

> *Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can  be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.*

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 3):

You say it's an ASP.NET application: in this case your .NET code will be running on the server, so you can't access the client's clipboard - nor can you call WinForms methods such as `MessageBox.Show`.

In response to comment:

> But it shows the message box with exact values ...

Are you debugging using Visual Studio and the Cassini web server?  In which case you might see the output of `MessageBox.Show` as it's running in the context of your current session.  But this won't work when you deploy to IIS.

Comment: But it shows the message box with exact values and it does not acess the clipboard function here